# How to connect to mysql localhost via ssh in python?

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I am trying to connect to a database on localhost mysql using ssh on python. Using the terminal and PyChar's datasource, connect to the database is obtained.

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (ssh_host, ssh_port),
    ssh_username=ssh_user,
    ssh_password=ssh_pass,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306),
    logger=create_logger(loglevel=1)) as tunnel:

with pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                     user=db_user,
                     passwd=db_pass,
                     db=db_name,
                     port=tunnel.local_bind_port) as connection:

    print("!!!!!!!!!CONNECTED!!!!!!!!!!!")
    output = connection.execute("select * from BD.b_catalog limit 1")
    print(output)
```

I am trying to connect using SSHTunnelForwarder but nothing comes out. I can't see the cherished print with a connection message.

Logger:

```
2020-10-09 17:19:39,977| WAR | MainThrea/0964@sshtunnel | Could not read SSH configuration file: ~/.ssh/config
2020-10-09 17:19:39,977| INF | MainThrea/0992@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from agent
2020-10-09 17:19:39,977| INF | MainThrea/1040@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from host directory
2020-10-09 17:19:39,977| INF | MainThrea/0910@sshtunnel | Connecting to gateway: 83.220.172.208:22 as user 'root'
2020-10-09 17:19:39,977| DEB | MainThrea/0915@sshtunnel | Concurrent connections allowed: True
2020-10-09 17:19:39,977| DEB | MainThrea/1367@sshtunnel | Trying to log in with password: *************
2020-10-09 17:19:40,155| INF | Srv-38583/1386@sshtunnel | Opening tunnel: 0.0.0.0:38583 <> 127.0.0.1:3306
2020-10-09 17:19:41,160| TRA |  Thread-3/0349@sshtunnel | #1 <-- ('127.0.0.1', 58390) to ('127.0.0.1', 3306) was rejected by the SSH server
2020-10-09 17:19:41,160| ERR |  Thread-3/0384@sshtunnel | Could not establish connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38583) to remote side of the tunnel
2020-10-09 17:19:41,160| INF | MainThrea/1407@sshtunnel | Shutting down tunnel ('0.0.0.0', 38583)
2020-10-09 17:19:41,221| WAR |  Thread-1/1819@transport | Success for unrequested channel! [??]
2020-10-09 17:19:41,260| INF | Srv-38583/1392@sshtunnel | Tunnel: 0.0.0.0:38583 <> 127.0.0.1:3306 released
2020-10-09 17:19:41,260| DEB | MainThrea/1421@sshtunnel | Transport is closed
```

And error message:

```
...
packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/home/kvando/PycharmProjects/py_scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 698, in _read_bytes
    raise err.OperationalError(
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Comment: Note that there is a difference between specifying `localhost` vs `127.0.0.1` with mysql. The former tries to connect to the local socket, rather than TCP.

Comment: Changing the address to localhost did not help, but thanks for the advice

Comment: @jordanm thanks, I added one second to wait after ssh connect, changed "127.0.0.1" to "localhost", removed the "with" clause, closed the connection manually after manipulating the database, and it all worked together for me.